# How to uniquely identify various URLs to the same page?

Tags: http, url

A lot of URL, specially blogs, articles are either represented by short URLs or there is a redirection that finally takes you to same URL from current one.
sometimes based on browser and other information, there are query string parameters that change.
What should be the logic on the server side to uniquely identify an article from different variations of its URL ?

Comment: So are you asking how you'd identify one article from various URIs? Like displaying the same article when you receive `/posts/1234` or `/posts/this-is-my-post-title`?

Comment: to be more specific, I am counting number of times a link has appeared in a list of tweets.
and then I realize that some of them are tiny URLs but all end up atthe same page.
also some URLs may differe by the way u have mentioned above.

Comment: Tiny Url sends a 301 response code with the original URL in the response. I think you should use a web crawler to crawl the list of URLs and have some special logic to handle redirection.